# Weird js file opens when OS starts. What is this?

Tags: javascript

There is a friend of mine who's running Windows XP. After she installed Dreamweaver CS6, everytime the OS starts, Dreamweaver opens automatically and shows this js file:

http://jsfiddle.net/H6YXw

Do you have any idea of what this could be?

I know it's not exactly a programming question, but since my familiarity with `JavaScript` is limited, I find no other way of knowing what this is.

Any thoughts would be very appreciated!

Comment: Instead of voting down this question, you could simply tell me this is not the right place for it. I would understand. I just thought I could get some help here.

Comment: A lot of these bizarre javascripts contain their own decoder, and decode to a link to advertising.  Usually an advertisement for a ripoff, hosted illegally on someone's forgotten, insecure website that was cracked into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's spyware, best get a Spyware scanner and run that. It's not Dreamweaver, but because the default file to open Javascripts would've been changed to Dreamweaver - so on start up it would open up Dreamweaver to edit the JS file